# CMS removing empty div or other element

Tags: cms

how can i easily stop empty elements from being removed by the CMS WYSIWYG editor?
it seems that changing the code is a very cumbersome way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `<div>&zwj;</div>` inside your empty element (div, p, a, span, h1, h2, ect..) to stop magento cms from removing them